# How can I make this set of Rails 3.1 queries more efficient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a `Sleep` model, instances of which `belongs_to` an instance of a `Person` model. I want to pass of calculation of statistics to a background thread. People self-report their data and may skip some days.

I created a `Sleepstat` model and plan to calculate some statistics for each day for which there is one or more recorded instances of `Sleep`. People may go back and edit their data later, however, so in this background task, I want to scan existing instances of `Sleepstat` to determine the status of the `needs_updating` flag.

If somebody creates a `Sleep` record on a day for which there is not an existing `Sleepstat`, then I want the background task to create the `Sleepstat` and calculate the statistics for that day. If somebody adds an additional `Sleep` record to a day that has an existing `Sleepstat` then I want to flag the `Sleepstat` as needs updating and update it with the new data, to keep the statistics up-to-date.

My thought was to do the following:

1. Run a query to return all `Sleep` records belonging to the `Person` in question. For that, I used this query, which works as I would expect:

   ```
   all_sleeps = Sleep.select('start_time,end_time,multiday,time_zone,in_progress').where(:person_id => self.id)
   ```
2. Create an array of the unique `start_time` dates:

   ```
   days_recorded = []
     for sleep in all_sleeps
       days_recorded.push sleep.start_time.to_date
     end
     days_recorded = days_recorded.uniq
   ```
3. For each of the `days_recorded`, look to see if a `Sleepstat` exists. If not, create one and calculate the statistics. If so, check whether it `needs_updating`. If so, calculate the statistics. If not, then move on to the next item in `days_recorded`.

   ```
   days_recorded.each do |d|
       stat = Sleepstat.where(:date => d).first

       if stat.nil?
         # No record, so create one because we have data for that day and calculate stats
         ...

       else
         # There is a record. Evaluate whether it needs to be updated

         if stat.needs_updating?
           # Update the Sleepstat
           ...

         end

       end
   end
   ```

This approach leads to a lot of independent queries:

```
Sleepstat Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "sleepstats".* FROM "sleepstats" WHERE "sleepstats"."date" = '2011-12-10'
Sleepstat Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "sleepstats".* FROM "sleepstats" WHERE "sleepstats"."date" = '2011-12-11'
Sleepstat Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "sleepstats".* FROM "sleepstats" WHERE "sleepstats"."date" = '2011-12-12'
Sleepstat Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "sleepstats".* FROM "sleepstats" WHERE "sleepstats"."date" = '2011-12-13'
```

My thought was to try to grab all of the `Sleepstat`s first, through a query like:

```
existing_stats = Sleepstat.where(:date => days_recorded)
```

and then to iterate through them in step 3. My attempt looked like:

```
    existing_stats = Sleepstat.where(:date => days_recorded)

    days_recorded.each do |d|
        stat = existing_stats.where(:date => d)

        if stat.nil? || stat.length == 0
          # No record, so create one because we have data for that day and calculate stats
          ...

        else
          # There is a record. Evaluate whether it needs to be updated

          if stat.needs_updating?
            # Update the Sleepstat
            ...

          end

        end
    end
```

This just led to a lot of more complex individual queries:

```
Sleepstat Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "sleepstats".* FROM "sleepstats" WHERE "sleepstats"."date" IN ('2011-12-07', '2011-12-06', '2011-12-08', '2011-12-09', '2011-12-10', '2011-12-11', '2011-12-12', '2011-12-13', '2011-12-14', '2011-12-15') AND "sleepstats"."date" = '2011-12-10'
Sleepstat Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "sleepstats".* FROM "sleepstats" WHERE "sleepstats"."date" IN ('2011-12-07', '2011-12-06', '2011-12-08', '2011-12-09', '2011-12-10', '2011-12-11', '2011-12-12', '2011-12-13', '2011-12-14', '2011-12-15') AND "sleepstats"."date" = '2011-12-11'
Sleepstat Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "sleepstats".* FROM "sleepstats" WHERE "sleepstats"."date" IN ('2011-12-07', '2011-12-06', '2011-12-08', '2011-12-09', '2011-12-10', '2011-12-11', '2011-12-12', '2011-12-13', '2011-12-14', '2011-12-15') AND "sleepstats"."date" = '2011-12-12'
Sleepstat Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "sleepstats".* FROM "sleepstats" WHERE "sleepstats"."date" IN ('2011-12-07', '2011-12-06', '2011-12-08', '2011-12-09', '2011-12-10', '2011-12-11', '2011-12-12', '2011-12-13', '2011-12-14', '2011-12-15') AND "sleepstats"."date" = '2011-12-13'
```

How can I improve the efficiency of this process so that I'm not hitting the database so many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your stats are not too heavy to calculate, you should better use a [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview)
to calculate the stats each time a record is created or updated :

```
Class Sleep < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :create_or_update_stats

  def create_or_update_stats
    # avoid calculation if record is new or if nothing changed
    return unless ( self.new_record? || self.changed? ) 

    date = self.start_time.to_date
    stats  = Sleepstat.find_or_create_by_date( date )
    sleeps = Sleep.where( date: date )

    # now calculate the stats and save them.
  end
end
```

**EDIT** of course, you'll have to add a callback on destroy, too. you get the spirit.

extra tips :

- don't use the `for` syntax. It internally calls `each`, so why bother ?
- this does the same thing you do in 2):

  ```
  all_sleeps.map{|s| s.start_date.to_date }.uniq
  # or even this
  all_sleeps.map( &:start_date ).map( &:to_date ).uniq
  ```
- to test if a relation is empty, use `stat.exists?` instead of your statement
- if you really need to do heavy calculations, you should take a look at [arel tables](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3) as they allow you to skip record instantiations and to only load the data that you need, providing a nice boost

Comment: Questions about `sleeps = Sleep.where( date: date )`... `Sleep` has the field `start_time` which I'm using to evaluate the date, so I'll need to cast that from a timestamp to a date. It's stored in UTC, however. How can I cast it to a date and retain the time zone information? Something like `sleep_on_date = Sleep.select('start_time,end_time,multiday,time_zone,in_progress').where('person_id = ? AND CAST(start_time AS DATE) = ?', self.id, the_date)`  (p.s. Using Postgres)

Comment: mmmm. dealing with time is always tricky (btw, sorry for the mistake). Especially because when people enter a Date / time on your site, they expect that the time they specify is on their time zone. I guess the good practice would be to detect client's time zone and convert the field to UTC, and to possibly detect client's time zone when displaying  to convert it back? On the other hand, it may be overkill... for a date. How many people will enter a DateTime that will effectively match with day +-1 in another timezone ?

Comment: Your problem is centered around the night. you already have chosen that a `sleep` would be linked to the day people felt asleep. This is a design matter... all things rounded up, why not store your date as three integer columns (day, month, year) with an index on them ? if you seek performance, that's the way to go i think

Comment: Well, I'm using Datetime fields at the moment, allowing them to specify a time zone (and set a default) and storing the time zone separately in a `time_zone` field. That may be overkill, but it works at the moment. I guess I can iterate through the records after the query, narrowing with Postgres `overlaps`, when I can convert the time zone properly.